# How to return previous width of elements in jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying out a simple animation effect. what i'm trying to do is , I'm trying to make the background(with color) of texts extend to the full width of a container on MouseOver , and return to it's default width on mouseout. however , given the number of texts with different default widths , is there a way to just set the mouseout event so that the background width will return to it's previous state/width? instead of setting a specific width for each ? (before the mouseover)

please find codes below :

html :

```
<div class="div4" style="border:solid 1px #CCC; height:180px; width:200px; text-align:left; background-color:#CCC; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px; outline:1px solid #999;">
<ul id="boombox" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none;">
<li><span style="background-color:yellow;">Yellow</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:red;">Red</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:green;">Green</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:blue;">Blue</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:#333;">Gray</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:orange;">Orange</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:brown;">Brown</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:black;">Black</span></li>
<li><span style="background-color:violet;">Violet</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
$("span").hover(function(){
$(this).animate({width:"100%"},"fast");
},function(){
$(this).animate({width:'....'},"slow"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/H2M8Z/)**

```
$("span").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('prevWidth', $(this).width())
    $(this).animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).attr('prevWidth')
    }, "slow");
});​
```

Comment: I'm getting notified of it on dreamweaver.

Comment: I have removed the error and updated answer, check it over here http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/H2M8Z/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time @Adil ! It works perfectly now , I wasn't aware that attr() could be used that way. 

Best regards,
Nathaniel